# How to get ssh under xterm not to break alt key?

Tags: ssh, vnc, xterm, utf-8

I have started running in an Ubuntu 16 VM, running tigervnc 1.7.0, and run into an odd environment.  Local windows behave as expected when I use alt-, for instance in a shell to back up a word via alt-b.  But when I use xterm to ssh to another host, it treats the character differently -- for example generating "â" rather than backing up.  Sounds like it's mapping the character differently, maybe via UTF.  But I haven't run into this on other systems.  I can't really tell if it's an issue with ssh, xterm, or the VNC server.

Googled and searched on ask ubuntu, but I'm coming up short.  If it's a dup, sorry, please point me the right direction.   I had high hopes for this one, but it seems different, as it's just ssh that's getting confused: [Alt key works on Ubuntu 14.04 VM, ignored on 15.10 VM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/759263/alt-key-works-on-ubuntu-14-04-vm-ignored-on-15-10-vm)

Answer (score 1):

I shared my question on facebook and got a pointer that at first I thought would be totally irrelevant, but actually pointed me toward the solution.

I added the following to my X environment and started a new xterm, which no longer suffered from the ALT problem.

> XTerm*eightBitInput: false

The solution was via the following, where someone had manually added *true* to their own environment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=163632

Looks like in my case, the new system has that as the system default, which I need to override.  Though I imagine there is a more elegant solution.